# ng build --prod have javaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am facing the below issue while using **ng build --prod**.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

Tried increasing the size limit by using https://github.com/endel/increase-memory-limit
but it is still failing to build. Do i need to change anywhere in the node_modules?

> 10% building modules 6/8 modules 2 active
>   ...\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap 90% chunk assets processing<--- Last
>   few GCs --->
>
> 174152 ms: Mark-sweep 1266.2 (1435.6) -> 1265.2 (1435.6) MB, 934.7 /
>   0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   175021 ms: Mark-sweep 1265.2 (1435.6) -> 1265.2 (1435.6) MB, 869.8 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   175964 ms:
>   Mark-sweep 1265.2 (1435.6) -> 1267.9 (1410.6) MB, 942.4 / 0.0 ms [last
>   resort gc].   176889 ms: Mark-sweep 1267.9 (1410.6) -> 1271.4 (1410.6)
>   MB, 924.1 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0000011C7D03FA99 
>       1: getLast(aka getLast) [E:\projects\Nila Company\memarane\front-end\node_modules\escope\lib\pattern-visitor.js:~45]
>   [pc=000002C336273AA1] (this=0000011C7D004241
>   ,xs=0000037217E78589 ,xs=0000037217E78589 )
>       2: Identifier [E:\projects\Nila Company\memarane\front-end\node_modules\escope\lib\pattern-visitor.js:76]
>   [pc=000002C335B8874A] (this=0000037217E78539
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

and my dependencies are :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@mm2/bsmodal": "^1.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.4.2",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-popper": "^1.0.0-beta-1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "aos": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jalali-moment": "^2.1.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.1",
    "ng2-datepicker-jalali": "^1.0.9",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Typescript version you are using?

if it is in 2.x.x, update to 2.7.x where they have fixed.

Comment: It's version is 2.3.3 as u see in dependencies section.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue with ionic 3 unit testing.

> npm test

was getting memory issue in above command then got it fixed with below commands--

> npm install
>
> node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

add maximumWarning and maximumError help me

"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "5mb",
"maximumError": "12mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "1mb",
"maximumError": "10mb"
}
],

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
npm install increase-memory-limit -g
```

then

```
increase-memory-limit
```

for more details, you can check 
[AOT build fails due to "JavaScript heap out of memory](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618#issuecomment-443879825)