# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, memory-leaks, build

Im getting this error when i run **ng build --prod**

> 92% chunk asset optimization <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [4136:0155D210]   443646 ms: Mark-sweep 703.5 (770.3) -> 703.6 (759.8)
>   MB, 2162.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking,
>   biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2163 ms) last
>   resort GC in old space requested [4136:0155D210]   445794 ms:
>   Mark-sweep 703.6 (759.8) -> 703.5 (759.8) MB, 2147.8 / 0.0 ms  last
>   resort GC in old space requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0369632D 
>       1: create(this=036856A9 )
>       2: _walk [034841A1 :~764] [pc=1CCAED1F](this=3A11A619 ,visitor=3BCEFD7D )
>       3: /* anonymous */ [034841A1 :~969] [pc=1D3728E3](this=3A11BCBD )
>       4: _walk [034841A1 :~968] [pc=1CCC1F3B](this=3A11BCBD
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory  1: node_module_register  2:
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewStruct  3:
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewPrototypeInfo

I tried everything. I reduced the usage of variables and checked for memory leaks and made very less callbacks in the ts file.

Im unable to figure out how to do it. I tried increasing the node memory by using **'npm i increase-memory-limit'** and increased the limit to **2GB**.

*Im using angular 4. Node version is 8.9.4*

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/66914674#66914674

Answer (score 7):

Try navigate to *yourproject*/node_modules and run following command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=5048 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" build --aot --prod
```

And if you want to make your life easier you can insert this in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
   "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
}
```

Then all you have to do now is running `npm run build-prod`.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I have not directed my project to node modules. May be other answers and solutions would have worked.
Thanks guys!!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I am currently using nohup npm start &, how can I replace with it npm run build-prod?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at how `increase-memory-limit` increases the heap size under the hood.

The usual way is as follows:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 server.js
```

If it is somehow modifying the `ng build` command you may want to try increasing the limit more.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error while running

> npm test run

For temporary, we can increase limit of  --max_old_space_size

> path: node_modules/@yarnpkg/index.js

then search for --max_old_space_size and then increase limit
but it will be a temporary solution.

**try this as it seems like permanent solution**--
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782016/1948482

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem once building a JS application and it turns out there's a limit of the memory a node module can consume.

simply using this npm package has solved it for me : https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: I already used the aproach to increase the memory. Please read my entire question.   https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit    , I Went to the link installed it and used it to increase the memory