# Angular FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: angular

I've used Angular 5
I try `ng build --prod`
show this error: 
`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685008/improving-production-build-time-for-angular-7-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906968/ng-build-prod-have-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error) and change `-max_old_space_size` in `package.json` but does not build production show above error again.
What's the problem? How can solve it? Is the problem of package.json؟

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "asd",
  "version": "0.6.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build",
    "build:prod": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot=false",
    "build:aot": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot",
    "build:aot2": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve",
    "serve": "npm run server:dev",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/ng test",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "ng": "ng",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false"
  },
  "private": true,
  ....
}
```

Comment: My ram memory of my system is 16 g

Comment: I have no idea about this error, but I would upgrade Angular to version 6. As far as I know, no one uses version 5. It's like the entire community skipped that version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Upgrading Angular at this time will not solve the issue (but may in the future). I get it with my Angular 7 and 8 projects as well on my Windows machine.

It looks like you need might to update your memory increase in the package.json. [Here is a link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13734#issuecomment-477455693) that seems to have solved it for a lot of people already, I think you have to specify the path to Angular CLI within node modules.

Instead of

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot
```

Try

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot
```

This path in the solution looks correct [back to Angular 4](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618).

Comment: Many Thanks, I wanted to compile the Angular project. And I got this error. But with your guidance, the problem was solved.

 node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve  --host 0.0.0.0

Comment: My project is in angular 7, and the node version is 18.5, and global angular version is 15, I used this command and it works for me, after many tries, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Run following command in cmd prompt :

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

i believe this, will fix your problem.

Answer (score 5):

First way:

Run as:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

where 8048 is new memory limit in megabytes (by default it's ~1500). Or add the command to package.json file:

```
"build-serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
```

and run as npm run build-serve

Or another way: The quick and effective solution for Windows

Open C:\Users\userName\%AppData%\Roaming\npm

Copy/paste the following code into your ng.cmd:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
    "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %* 
) ELSE (
    @SETLOCAL 
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;% 
    node --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %* 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192`

This helped me on Linux. I found this solution on:
https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360002046418-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1):

update node.js to 12 version help me

Answer (score 0):

No single solution above worked for me. However, the combination below solved the problem:

1. Update Node.js to latest version (v.12.19.0 LTS in my case)
2. Build the app with increased JS heap limit allocation, by running the following command: `node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Angular 12. In this case running

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production
```

helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem in github actions. I am using dockerfile for building image. I finally found where should I write the "`node --max_old_space_size=8000`" command.
I wrote
"`RUN node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`"
instead of
"`RUN ng build --prod`" in DOCKERFILE